# Need to Identify a Scifi Short Story in an Anthology about London Tailor for Aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I remember the story, which is as follows:

A humble tailor (with his disabled wife as help) on the outskirts of London was suddenly visited by a couple of men in suits who closed his shop and told him he has a special assignment. They introduced him to a centaur type alien, who speaks English just fine with a translator, and they need him to whip up something so the alien can be presented to Her Majesty at a formal function.

The tailor refused to make a "glorified horse blanket" and ended up spending two weeks making jackets, pantaloons, shirts, even undies, after having a fit with the MI5 guy. But the end result was remarkable, even though the wife thought the tailor was just joking about the alien (you're making it for a stage play, right?)

I am reasonably sure it was one of Jerry Pournelle's collections "There Will Be War" or "Star Empire" but I can't remember which one.

A little help?

Comment: It's definitely in one of Pournelle's Empire collections. If no one runs it down before I get back to my library I should be able to help.

Comment: I am seeing a similar sounding story reported as "Custom Fitting" by James White, appearing in Stellar #2. cannot find a good summary though.
see http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?33185

Comment: Valorum gets the win. It's in volume two of *Imperial Stars* if you are still interested. That's the "Republic and Empire" one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [AbeBooks BookSleuth](http://forums.abebooks.fr/discussions/AbeBookscouk_BookSleuth/Science_Fiction/Bespoke_Tailoring_for_Alien/abeSleuthUK/1311.1?redirCnt=1&nav=messages)

> I am looking for a book of sci-fi short stories. The one story I
> remember out of it is where a tiny tailorshop in London is approached
> by a govenment representative to make a sort of "horse blanket" for
> what turns out to be Earth's first visiting alien.
>
> The alien very much resembles a centaur. In the course of measuring
> the equinid for his **glorified horse blanket**, the tailor asks, as good
> tailors do, the intended purpose of the garment. The which the visitor
> replies, that he will be wearing it to present his credentials as
> Ambassador of the Intergalactic Federation to the Court of St. James.
>
> The tailors relationship with the govenment rep went downhill from
> there.

- 

> **The short story is "Custom Fitting" by James White. I have it in a
> short story collection called "[Futures Past](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?215853)" which is available from
> various stores here on abe. I don't know about the copy with the
> ambassador on the front but "Futures Past" contains the short story
> you have mentioned.**

> <sub><sup>[deeden](http://forums.abebooks.fr/discussions/AbeBookscouk_BookSleuth/Science_Fiction/Bespoke_Tailoring_for_Alien/abeSleuthUK/1311.1?redirCnt=2&nav=messages)</sup></sub>